# Java Spring соединение из докер-контейнера с БД

Tags: java, spring, docker, rethinkdb

Хочу запустить свой сервис, написанный на спринге, в докер-контейнере. Сервис работает с `RethinkDB`, который уже запущен в контейнере. Контейнер с `RethinkDB` открыл порты 8080, 28015 и 29015. Я могу подключиться к этой БД снаружи - например, набрав в браузере адрес админки `localhost:8080` или запустив сервис в IDE, при этом сервис успешно соединяется с БД.

Когда я пытаюсь запустить сервис в контейнере, вылетает ошибка подключения к БД:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:400)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:243)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:225)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:402)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
    at com.rethinkdb.net.SocketWrapper.connect(SocketWrapper.java:53)
    ... 69 common frames omitted
```

Почему-то два сервис из контейнера не может подключиться к БД, даже если запустить ее не в контейнере, а на хосте.

Как решить эту проблему? Как БД, так и сервис в конечном итоге должны работать в докере.

Докер-файл для сервиса написан так:

```
FROM openjdk:10-jre
EXPOSE 8086
COPY my_app-1.1.jar /app.jar
COPY newrelic/ /newrelic/
CMD ["/usr/bin/java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

Comment: localhost из контейнера, и localhost локально- разные вещи, вам нужна правильная строка конекшна

Comment: @VladMamaev, то есть, ни localhost, ни 127.0.0.1 не позволит подключиться из контейнера к БД? Тогда как поступить? Если передавать 127.0.0.1 через переменные окружения, это будет то же самое, что и захардкодить этот адрес.

Comment: @VladMamaev, использовать --network=?

Comment: если база тоже в контейнере, то использовать имя контейнера вместо localhost